# Nested string replace using C++

Tags: c++, replace

I want to replace every single variables in a string with specified strings.

```
namespace math {

    map<string,string> setVar;

    string setVariable(string& str, const map<string,string>& variables) {
        for(auto& m : variables) {
            size_t pos;
            while((pos=str.find(m.first)) != string::npos)
                str.replace(pos,m.first.length(),"("+m.second+")");
        }
        return str;
    }
    bool isStillContainVariable(const string& str, const map<string,string>& variables) {
        for(auto& m : variables)
            return (str.find(m.first)!=string::npos) ? false : true;
        return false;
    }
    vector<string> makeToken(string& str) {
        if(setVar.size()!=0) {
            str = setVariable(str,setVar);
            str = isStillContainVariable(str,setVar) ?
                        setVariable(str,setVar) : str;
        }
        cout << str << endl;

        vector<string> res;
        .....     //I tokenize the string
        return res;
    }
}
```

If I use the following code it reaplce the string correctly.

```
int main() {
    string str = "-(-(x)+lg(y)+5+ln(z))";
    math::setVar["x"] = "lg(pi*lg(y))";
    math::setVar["y"] = "z";
    math::setVar["z"] = "10";
    auto res = math::makeToken(str);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I use the following code, the solution is just `(x)`, but the correct solution would be `sin(pi)`

```
string str = "z";
math::setVar["x"]="sin(y)";
math::setVar["y"]="pi";
math::setVar["z"]="x";
auto res = math::makeToken(str);
```

After the replace the `string` will not contain any kind of variables if the replace is correct.

I have complety no idea how to reaplce the string.

Comment: `isStillContainVariable` seems flawed. You don't want to return false immediately if you don't find the first value from the map. Instead you should only return true if you do find it, otherwise you want the loop to continue through the rest of the values to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of loop within `makeToken`:

```
while (isStillContainsVariables(...))
{ ... do the replacement ... }
```